# Masonry not working for Twitter widget

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some Javascript that pulls recent tweets from a user. It looks like this:

```
getTwitters('tweet', { id: 'LadyGaga', count: 8, enableLinks: true, ignoreReplies:   
false, clearContents: true, template: '%text% <a class="arrow"   
href="http://twitter.com/%user_screen_name%/statuses/%id_str%/" target="_blank"></a>'  
});
```

The tweets are loaded as lists dynamically into

```
<div id=tweet"></div>
```

with

```
$(window).load(function () { $('#tweet').masonry(); });
```

however for some reason it is not working :( I have done it this way for ever and I have no clue why it would do this.

My CSS is safe as well:

```
#tweet {
margin-left:-43px;
}

#tweet li {
list-style:none;
padding:5px;
margin:0 0 3px 3px;
background:url('http://static.tumblr.com/ux4v5bf/wM2lywrxr/aeeatagsd.png') repeat;
float:left;
width:88px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at my code again and figured I had to target ul of tweet rather than tweet itself. Haha silly me.